# "FirebaseError: Unauthenticated" when call a "Callable Function" with "Emulator"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In production environment exists a lot of answers to adjust google cloud console, but for development with function emulator, there is nothing.

Using `onRequest` to call with HTTP works, but `onCall` with SDK I get "FirebaseError: Unauthenticated".

Answer (score 1):

Works after set a **App Check** with **reCAPTCHA v3** usign `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. Set different recaptcha for *dev* and *prod* environments.

Guide for web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider